# Javascript, displaying a transparent image.

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    #container { 
    width: 320px; 
    height: 480px;
    border: 1px solid red;

    }
</style>

</head>
<body>


<div style="position: relative;" id="container">
 <canvas id="myCanvas" width="320" height="480" 
   style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: 0;"></canvas>
    <canvas id="plane" width="320" height="480" 
   style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: 0;"></canvas>

 <canvas id="canvas2" width="100" height="100" 
   style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: 1;"></canvas>
</div>
<img id="scream" src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-BrJHwoqM2qg/Uq94Il8t-1I/AAAAAAAAD7s/vyFLZUgMkdA/s1600/Plane.png" alt="The Scream" width="0" height="0">



<script>
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var c2=document.getElementById("canvas2");
var c3=document.getElementById("plane");

var plane;
var ground;
var score1 = "1"
var score = score1;
var increase = 6;
var delay = 40;
var scorez;

start();

function start(){
    backgrounds();
    planeDraw();
    var scorez = setInterval(scoring, delay);

}


function backgrounds(){
    var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
    var my_gradient=ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0,0, 280);
    my_gradient.addColorStop(0,"white");
    my_gradient.addColorStop(1,"blue");
    ctx.fillStyle=my_gradient;
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,320,480);

    ground = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillStyle="black";
    ctx.fillRect(0,450 , 320 ,30);

}

function scoring(){
    scores();
    score2();

}
function scores(){
    score -= 3-(3+increase);
}
function score2(){
    //var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas2');
    var context = c2.getContext('2d');
    context.clearRect(0, 0, c2.width, c2.height);
    var w = c2.width;
    c2.width = 1;
    c2.width = w;

    var text=c2.getContext("2d");
    text.font="20px Georgia";
    text.fillText(score ,15,20);

}


function hit(){

}

function loes(){
    clearInterval(scorez);

}

function planeDraw(){
    plane = c3.getContext('2d');
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = "http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-BrJHwoqM2qg/Uq94Il8t-1I/AAAAAAAAD7s/vyFLZUgMkdA/s1600/Plane.png"; //transparent png

    plane.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 320, 100);

}
</script> 
<!--
http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-BrJHwoqM2qg/Uq94Il8t-1I/AAAAAAAAD7s/vyFLZUgMkdA/s1600/Plane.png

--!>
</body>
</html>
```

All the code seems to be working fine, the only issue I am finding is the image of the plane is not printing. Could some one please tell me what I am doing wrong. Thank you.
When I changed the planeDraw function to create a rectangle it worked perfectly. As well as this the code worked in JSFiddle, when it was isolated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are drawing the image before it has loaded.

Load the plane image once, and draw it after its `onload` event has fired.

If you can, consider embedding the image as a `data:` URL, as this will remove the need for waiting for the image to load, however keep in mind that it makes your code bigger!

Comment: How would I add it as a data file? Thank you

Comment: Personally I use a PHP command-line script: `<?php echo 'data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode(file_get_contents($_SERVER['argv'][1]));` Run that and it will output the `data:` URL for your image.

Comment: Ahahahaha I did know that, far out I am slow today. I was thinking about doing it in js which is impossible right?
Secondly onload where abouts would I put this into my code?

Comment: If you have the `.src = '..'` code somewhere in your initialisation, and `.drawImage` inside a rendering loop, then you don't need `onload` - it just won't draw the plane until it has loaded.

Answer (score 1):

You have to wait for the image to load before drawing it.
Try:

```
img.onload = function()
{
    plane.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 320, 100);
};
img.src = "http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-BrJHwoqM2qg/Uq94Il8t-1I/AAAAAAAAD7s/vyFLZUgMkdA/s1600/Plane.png"; //transparent png
```

It's best to define the onload function before setting the src attribute - depending on the browser, if the image file is in your cache, the onload event may fire as soon as the src is set (before you have a chance to define onload).

Comment: Where abouts would I put this into my code, I do not quiet understand this concept. Probably because of the time of day sorry.

Comment: in planeDraw(), just after creating the new Image object